# DocuSign Api. How to let signer edit a text tab with a sample text?

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I am trying to put a text box near "NAME:" and I would like the signer to fill the box.
Client has asked to put a guide/ghost text like "name here".
If I send the envelope with "value" already set, it will not let the signer to modify it.

Does somebody know how or already had this problem ?
Thanks in advance

code:

```
"textTabs": [{
"tabLabel": "Name",
*"value": "name here",*  <-- (?)
"anchorString": "Charterer full name:",
"anchorXOffset": "1.2",
"anchorYOffset": "-0.1",
"anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "false",
"anchorUnits": "inches"
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add locked=false, to make tab not be readonly, like this:

```
"textTabs": [{
"tabLabel": "Name",
"value": "name here",
"locked": "false",
"anchorString": "Charterer full name:",
"anchorXOffset": "1.2",
"anchorYOffset": "-0.1",
"anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent": "false",
"anchorUnits": "inches"
}]
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. This do the job.

I'd ask further, is it possible to design it in a way that "when you click the box, the text disappear. Letting you write your own" ?
Right now someone has to delete the prior text.
My advice was to put something like a note (I still have to research if it is possible) besides or on the text box (should be always visible). Thank you again !!

Comment: Not with a text tab, at this moment, it does not behave like a textbox on a web page. I would recommend to use a label for the example text and not populate the tab with that value.

Comment: Another option is to add validation, where the same value "Your name here" is the only invalid value, and if that value is entered - you can give them an error and they cannot sign.

Comment: oh, just thought of another idea for you - you can do a tooltip, tooltip is shown only no the web though, not on mobile devices

Comment: Really appreciate, gave me lot of tips to work on